# how to declare 2 canvas / how to draw on 2 canvas? (dual-screen game)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I have created a 2-part layout (see the .xml file below), and I want to perform some "canvas.drawBitmap()" on either the top or the bottom part of this 2-part layout (à la Nintendo DS's dual screen system, you see).

I'm surely missing an easy point, but I can't figure how to do that.

Thank you very much for your help!

Here's my main.xml:

```
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#FF0000">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it. That will let people know that your problem is solved.

Comment: As a new comer, it seems that I can't do it for the 8-or-so hours, but, yes, I'll do it when I'll be able. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to the following topic: 
[SurfaceView in Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185624/surfaceview-in-layout)

Here's the relevant code (added in the Activity's OnCreate() function)

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout surface1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view1);
    surface1.addView(new MVCView(model, this));

    LinearLayout surface2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view2);
    surface2.addView(new MVCView(model, this));
```